# How Program Becomes a Process. How OS makes Program a process

Tags: c++, c, process, operating-system

I wanted to know How OS actually makes a program in to process. what are steps Os engages to make program a process.

I mean How a Program becomes a Process, what are the parameter OS adds to kernel datastructure before making a program a process

Thank you in advance.

Comment: A particular OS you have in mind?

Comment: It was on the news this mroing a user in ar who had kill her process . they are taking the process back to redmont too lady to rest my pary are with the proccess who lost his spawn ; i am truley sorry for your lots

Comment: LOL@Pete, maybe the question should be retitled How is process formed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every operating system is going to do this in a different manner.

However, in general the following steps will occur in a modern operating system:

- New address space created
- Program image loaded into an agreed upon address

  - This may involve [relocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relocatable_code) of the image, or a dependency.
- Execution "context" setup

  - Includes stack, and a call into an agreed upon "main" function by a logical thread of execution

I'm glossing over lots of nasty little details, but that's a basic overview.

Comment: @Kevin. Thank you so much for the answer. I am in need of bit detail. i would request you to explain a bit or give me some link/doc. i am interested in low level stuff. 

LIke you answer :)

Comment: @mahesh - I confess I do not routinely work on operating systems :)  Pretty much everything I learned in this area came from a project (http://www.owlnet.rice.edu/~comp421/projects/lab2.html which focuses on "imaginary" hardware) and a later edition of Jason's linked book.  If you're looking for something in particular I might know though.

Comment: @kevin, thank you so much for timely reply. I am crazy about OS, Loader, Linker and Compilers. If you have something related to that, i hope  you have :), please let me know links/docs etc. Would be great if you could provide :). Thanks once again.

Answer (score 3):

[image]
    

[Operating System Concepts](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471250600)

Answer (score 0):

There's a tonne of info on the net...

- [Delve into UNIX process creation](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-unixprocess.html) (IBM)
- [Windows Processes and Threads](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=362660&seqNum=2) (InformIT)

Comment: Those 2 are different from my question :)

Comment: @mahesh: Then you should elaborate on what you're looking for as they seem perfectly germane to your question.